# Get pluggable databases in a stopped Oracle container database?

Tags: windows, oracle

I'm trying to write a script that gets the Oracle container databases and their pluggable databases on a given server. I can get these handily enough when the CDB is open - but is there a way to get the PDB's of a closed/stopped container database? The databases are on Windows and I'm writing the script in PowerShell.

Any help would be much appreciated.